# Am I obligated to work on a project unrelated to my thesis because PI asked me to?

Tags: research-process, advisor

My principal investigator (PI) got a grant from a company and wants me to work on this. However, this is not related to my thesis at all and we might not be able to publish anything on this.

My question is: am I obligated to work on this just because I'm part of the lab?

This is in no way related to my thesis and I'm not interested in the work simply because I'm the one who is going to have to stay late working on it and not get anything in return.

Comment: You are never obligated to work on anything - at the very worst, you could just resign. But my answer, and the others, give some reasons why you should give it careful consideration even if it is unrelated to your thesis.

Comment: What in the seven hells is a PI? I thought that PI was a mathematical constant, defined as the ration between the circumference and the diameter.

Comment: @ApplePI "PI" stands for "principal investigator."

Comment: @MadJack: That should go in the question so that everybody can understand it. This website is for the whole world, not just the USA.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair point. Edited. Though, after poking around a bit on Google, I'm not so sure I accept the claim that "PI" is a US-only acronym.

Comment: @MadJack: I didn't make any such claim, but from this comment thread alone it's obviously not a common term, and from its Wikipedia article it seems to be heavily US-leaning at the very least. I infer that it's more commonplace in the US than elsewhere because so far only the non-US contributors to this question have not understood it or even realised that it could be not-understood. Doesn't hurt to write it out in full, no matter where it comes from, so that the uninitiated can look up the term if they need to!

Comment: Tone down a little. PI is a pretty well known term outside of US if you are active in academia. Also, someone from US may not realize what lingo people use in other countries.

Comment: Just a point to consider: what you are obliged to do and not, is one thing. What you can use for leverage to help your career is another thing. If you want to be at least moderately successful in any career, you should consider doing more than obligated. 
Does this side job gives you a broader network? Does is make you more important in the group? ==  Can you use it to ask more support, money etc from your supervisor? Will it help you to land a job or a similar grant later?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dave's answer is great. To add a different perspective, you should definitely put more thought into what you want to get out of graduate school. [Grades don't matter once you leave graduate school](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=469). However, your publication count definitely does, as does the people with whom you've collaborated, the technical and research skills you've gained, the understanding of how a research lab works, presentation skills, networking skills, and your ability to subsist on ramen noodles.

It's very easy for a graduate student to lose sight of what's important, particularly when it just looks like "work on this". At the very least, I would talk with your graduate advisor or another professor in the department to get their perspective on the task you're being asked to do. It may very well be something very useful for your career, even though at first blush it seems like busywork.

To bring this back to your immediate question, the only research you *need* to do is the research upon which your funding is based. If this does not fall into that category, you are under no obligation to do the requested project. However, I strongly recommend you consider the benefit that performing this research may provide in the long run; most likely, it's something that will in some way or other make you a more skilled (and marketable) researcher when you're done.

Comment: +1. I got way too distracted during my PhD. Mainly because writing papers was a difficult thing I had to learn and there was always an easier side project to finish. One of the most important things you can learn, not just as a PhD, but as a scientist is to say no to distractions. Sometimes even if they _are_ technically obligations.

Comment: But he said _"and we might not be able to publish anything on this"_… (then he accepted this answer anyway, so wtf nevermind)

Answer (score 22):

I don't know the details of your situation, but you should keep in mind my personal rule #1 of academic research:

> ***Rule #1.*** You should *always* have a publication in mind for research you work on, unless there is some other very tangible benefit that makes it worth the time.

This rule is motivated by the fact that your vita showcases the publications you produce (and the grants you receive), but not the projects you work on. You want to make sure that you get due recognition for your efforts, which means turning them into publications. The more often you can employ rule #1, the better.

Are you certain that you cannot find a way to get a publication out of this project, perhaps by broadening it slightly?

The second thing to keep in mind is that, in a group research lab, it is very reasonable to do some work that is not related to your thesis. Of course, you must also work on your thesis, but it does not need to be the only thing you do. Having a more broad vita when you graduate is a real benefit if you are applying to postdocs and other positions.

Finally, are you getting paid out of the PIs grants? If so, that is perhaps a more tangible reason to work on the projects that fund those grants.

Comment: Actually my advisor is rather new and so the university is the one paying. Whether it is because i'm paid through my advisor, part of my question is if  in case I refuse to work on this,  can he just fire me or something like that? as I outline in one comment below i'm already doing quite some progress with my own work and beyond.

Comment: @JDoe: Of course anything *could* happen, but it would be a very low probability travesty if a student in good standing in an academic program "got fired" for wanting to prioritize his own academic work over his advisor's non-academic external project.  If your advisor is rather new, he may not understand how things work very clearly either.  You should not hesitate to talk to him about this.

Comment: I think it is not too common for an advisor to "fire" someone in the middle of the academic year. But if your interests are too different, the advisor may not want to fund the the next year (the same would be true if a student just wasn't getting anything done, etc.).  Especially in grant-dependent labs, the PIs will want to have personnel who contribute towards the work of the lab.

Comment: It's sad that this is rule #1. Arguably, the goal of research should be to create new knowledge, no matter whether there's a 10 page article on the horizon or not.

Comment: @Raphael: I can sympathize with that. I want to state the rule very bluntly, though, because sometimes there are new faculty who don't realize that even if they work really hard, if they don't produce any products they will not get ahead in academia. Of course, once someone is productive (and/or tenured), they can spend some time on higher risk projects. But one common characteristic of successful researchers is that they choose most of their projects where they are able to produce products in the end (to the extent that this is possible).

Answer (score 10):

The literal answer to your question is certainly **no**.  In fact academics are surprisingly rarely *obligated* to do anything -- one might call this one of the perks of the profession.  Or one might call it one of the pitfalls: failure to do things that other people strongly expect you to do may have negative consequences.  These consequences can come with enough of a time delay so that some academics acquire the illusion of complete autonomy and freedom to do absolutely whatever they want...until they get a rude (sometimes fatal to their career) awakening.

Since you use the term PI, may we assume that you are a graduate student and that your advisor is the PI on a grant which is at least partially funding your schooling?  In that case, if you give a "hard no" then depending on the circumstances you might be viewed as simply not doing the work upon which your funding was made conditional, and it is possible that you could lose your funding and/or your standing in the program.

So you almost certainly shouldn't "just say no".  You sound unclear on your obligations, and that sounds very stressful.  You should have a lengthy, non-confrontational conversation with your PI clarifying the nature of your funding, what he expects in return, and so forth.  In fact it would be even better to do some research about this in advance, including talking to at least one other faculty member in your department (e.g. the director of graduate studies), as one faculty member's understanding of a student's responsiblities is not necessarily the standard one or even guaranteed to be correct.  But if you have some kind of research assistantship, you should have a total number of hours per week that you are working in the lab.  Asking you to work at night *in addition* to what you're already doing sounds so unreasonable that it is probably not even what your PI has in mind.  If you find out that you have, say, 20 hours a week of work in the lab and are already filling that with preassigned projects including your own thesis work, then of course the PI is going to have to clarify how you are going to take on a new project: what is going to get dropped instead?  I find it unlikely that your PI will look you in the eye and tell you to stop working on your thesis in order to do this new project.

Finally, from someone who obviously has no idea of the particulars of your situation, let me say that you sound perhaps overly negative about this.  You say that "we might not be able to publish anything on this".  To me at least that's an almost vacuous statement: publications are rarely *guaranteed*, and guaranteed publications are among the least valuable.  If your PI is working on this and inviting you to work on it, then I find it more reasonable that this is a promising academic project from which you can benefit.  Being involved in more than one academic project as a graduate student can be very valuable.  So unless there is more to the story (which could certainly be the case), maybe this is actually an opportunity rather than a problem for you.  Maybe.

Comment: I do understand you last paragraph, but the work seems to be very specific for the company and they wouldn't want to give this away. of course i'm putting the worst case scenario to really understand what is it that i'm in control of. There has been this kind of work in the lab before where the postdoc did some non-chanllenging work (plating, counting colonies for an antibiotic resistance study) The lab did not get anything from it in my perspective. My PI might keep whatever funding he got and the postdoc didn't get any sort of tangible recognition in exchange. While the postdoc kept his job.

Comment: I don't think I should submit myself to things that are not in my priority, when my interest is research and not just use my time for the sake of the lab. I understand I sound negative but i'm the only grad student in the lab, and i'm the only one getting publications plus working computationally and wet lab.

Comment: @JDoe: If the work is with a private company and is not affiliated with your prior funding and/or your own studies in any way, then "your PI" is not your PI *on this project*, and the direct negative consequences of not doing it become much lessened.  But in any case you should talk to your PI about it, carefully and non-confrontationally.  If your PI/advisor feels very strongly that you should be working on an esentially non-academic project, then to my mind s/he is not being a good advisor, and you may want to find another.  (This is a common enough occurrence.)

Comment: @JDoe: the key is to balance your own interests with the interests of the lab. Remember that you will ask the PI to write a letter of recommendation from you - that does not mean passively agreeing to every demand, but it does mean making a reasonable effort to be a team player, if you want the PI to write a letter that says you are a team player.  So saying "yes" to everything isn't good, but saying "no" to everything isn't better. To get ahead in academia, you have to find ways to advance your own interests while also helping others advance theirs.

Answer (score 6):

I have a different perspective from the other answers on this. For what follows, I'm assuming that you are in the US and are employed as a graduate research assistant (GRA) with your professor as a your direct employment supervisor. Additionally, if the only money available to your professor to pay your salary is money from this grant, then they may ask you to work on this project since it is paying the bills. This is true regardless of whether or not it has anything to do with your interests, thesis, or anything else. It would be unethical for you to be paid by with this money and to not work on the funder's project.

Now your funding may be funneled through the department and university so that your checks have the university's name on them, but if your professor has designated this account to pay for part of your time, you should spend that part of your time working on this project. It might not be in your best interest to do so, since it might not lead to your thesis or any other publication, but if this is the source of the funds your professor has to pay your salary, you need to do that work. Otherwise he could fire you, and he could get into trouble with the funder if he pays you with their money but you don't do the work.

Now, your professor may have several other sources of money and may choose to pay you using this money rather than some other money. That's his right. They may have picked you to do this work because they think you will be better at it than other members of the lab. But that's pretty irrelevant. If this money is used to cover your salary, then you need to do the work, ask to be moved to other funding, quit, or be fired.

If you have your own funding, say a departmental, university, or government fellowship, then you wouldn't be obligated to do the work. But, in my experience, a professor who knew you had your own funding wouldn't ask you to work on an unrelated project and would hire someone else to work on the project instead.

It's not your status as a member of the lab that obligates you to work on particular things, but the source of the funds for your salary.

Comment: The scenario in the first paragraph seems quite specific and extreme (and sounds like it may be contradicted by further information provided by the OP in comments, although his situation is not very clear).  The grant is something that the PI got after the OP started working for him, so it is probably not part of the terms he agreed to when he accepted the position.  In my opinion, switching a student's funding and thus his required activities is quite unethical unless he came knowing that his funding status was in jeopardy.

Comment: For that, matter, you write: "It would be unethical for you to be paid by with this money and to not work on the funder's project." That is not clear to me.  I have funded students in the summer off of my NSF grant.  They did not work for me in any reasonable sense and at no point did I report what they did (or didn't do...) during the summer to the NSF.  The point is that I got permission to use part of the grant for *student summer support*.  Many grants fund students to do their own work in this way: that's pretty much what "student funding" means to me.

Comment: In the scenario that you sketch: at the very least, shouldn't the OP's advisor have informed him of this in advance and given him the opportunity to apply for a more desirable source of funding?  There are both internal and external scholarship opportunities for students, the OP could ask for (more) teaching, and forth.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, depending on the terms of the grant, I would guess you are wrong. It's summer student support for work on the grant, not summer student support for whatever. My institution requires that I certify that myself and all people paid on my grants worked the fraction of the time we paid them *on the grant*, and this is required, more or less, by the government. On the first point, I agree that it would be unethical, but if the prof is new, has few to no grants, and the project the student was hired on had recently ended, the prof may not have much choice.

Comment: Yes, but if part of the project is to fund summer students....which is routinely written into the budget of the grant application.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, I agree, but since we don't have enough info to know, the question is best answered by saying that OP is obligated to do the work if that is what he is being paid to do. If the professor ruined OP's life by not finding the right funding, that's bad, but it may be the best way to stay employed.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark unless it's an REU, it's a project to fund summer student to WORK ON THE PROJECT, no? Not just to work on whatever Pete say, right?

Comment: What I'm saying is "no".  Most NSF grant applications in my field do not include a section saying what students will do...because students are doing *their own work*, not helping the PI.  In many parts of mathematics, many students could not help the PI in any meaningful way.  Also "to work on whatever I say" is not right either, because you make it sound like they are doing my work.  They're not.  They're doing what they want to and what they can, and I'm helping them with it.

Comment: (Also REUs are for undergraduates.  The US government has many sources of summer funding for graduate students which are not connected to any one faculty member's research: VRG, RTG, GAANN....In fact I have never met a PhD student in pure mathematics who had funding tied to working in a lab or doing any specific work for their advisor.)

Comment: I think I see what you're talking about now. I think, in this case, that you have a special kind of grant (an RTG) that really only applies to theoretical mathematics. These are actually kind of unusual in my experience, and making them sound normal isn't helping OP. My apologies for the flippant comment about doing what Pete says, as well. All that being said, NSF usually cares that the students work on the grant. If the purpose of the grant is training students, then that is the purpose and what they do is on point. If it's more topical, they're going to want progress by the student.

Comment: No, what I said first applied to an individual NSF grant.  But I agree that this is probably not the situation the OP is in.  Also, I must admit that it is harder to get summer funding for students on individual NSF grants than it used to be.  Sometimes this funding is cut from funded grants and sometimes it isn't, and the reasons for this are quite opaque.  Finally: I certainly agree that if it is part of the OP's funding contract to work on this particular project, then he is obligated to work on it or forego at least some portion of his funding.  He should find out...

Comment: Still, theoretical mathematics is different. I've had and have tons of grants with students on them from NSF. Grants often just come to and end after years or longer after maximal no-cost extensions. Frankly, when I was in school, I rarely knew what grants I was being paid on, and it didn't matter to anyone what I was working on too much as long as I made progress. But it is very common to have grants in other fields that require students to make progress on the subject of the grant. And if OP's prof is thinly funded, some flexibility in subject might be required.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no.  Longer answer: Might this benefit you in some way?  If the answer to that is no then you absolutely should politely decline with the excuse being that you want to work on your thesis and that's your priority.  But consider whether you might somehow benefit in the long run from participation.  You should not expect a better grade, nor should your grade be contingent on your accepting this project.  It might, however, put you in a better spot in the lab, lead to employment, lead to compensation, help with a letter of recommendation, etc.

tl;dr: Don't do it if you think you can't get anything out of it.  But first consider very carefully whether or not you really can't get anything out of it.

Answer (score 3):

Some good (IMO) reasons to take on the work:

- Does it require a new technique (or a modification to one you already use)?  If so it builds your skills, and your next recruitment will be based on skills rather than grades.
- Does it get you contacts outside your institution?  This is more likely than you think if your data isn't as clear as they were expecting, and recruiters (postdoc or otherwise) will want to hear about external collaborations.
- Are you *sure* you won't get any thesis material out of it?  Even a couple of pages about a more general use of something you're doing can be useful in some cases.
- You say "might not be able to publish".  Alternatively that could be put as "I might get a paper out of this".  That would be a good thing, *especially* if it's not in your core area, as it demonstrates flexibility and opens up more roles to apply for in the future.

However it might need some managing:

- Maybe along the lines of "yes, but I need to get [some data on your core project] first".
- If this is a piece of commercial work, it may bring some non-grant funding with it.  Some of that may be available for you (I've seen this happen, extra cash is a good way to get a volunteer to work a Saturday).  Of course this may be ruled out in your system.
- Find out about whether you would be allowed to publish worthwhile results.  Often engineering/technology companies want to publish so long as they don't have to put too much effort in to writing the paper.  If you get the data and write the paper, you should probably be first author (not always, e.g. your supewrvisor developed a clever technique which hasn't yet been published, you're just applying it).

I got a paper and a results chapter from a measurement that started like this.  The sample arrived when I was bogged down in an experiment that wasn't going anywhere, and what I needed turned out to be a break from the core work to work on a problem that could be solved in a reasonable timescale.

Answer (score 2):

All of the above responses offer good advice.  If any of your funding is coming from the project, then you should certainly feel some obligation to work on it.  If not, then you are right to have reservations about it taking time away from your thesis work, though it still might be valuable experience.

However, if you are in the sciences there is something else to be considered - the politics of grad school.  If your advisor is a reasonable and mature person, you should be able to talk to them about your concerns, and decide together whether it is something you should do.  The trouble is that a very large percentage of academic scientists are NOT reasonable or mature people, even if they at first appear to be.  Getting a PhD is often more about stroking the correct egos and being a good little minion than it is about your skills, abilities, or grades.  With far too many advisors, if you don't follow orders or do everything they expect you to do FOR THEM, then there's a good chance that they will decide you don't deserve a PhD, and you will get unexpectedly screwed somewhere down the line.  I've seen it happen time and time again over stupid stuff.

They may not do anything as obvious as firing you, but they can make sure you don't pass your comprehensives, don't get the funding to continue, or they can suddenly drop the project and you with it.  They can also just make your life miserable until you quit.  University rules are meaningless when it comes to grad students - professors can pretty much do whatever they want with you and change the rules at will, and there's nothing you can do about it.  In one of my programs, a single professor with political clout changed the format, content, and committee of examiners for the comprehensive exams THE DAY BEFORE IT WAS GIVEN, to insure that only the people he personally felt were "worthy" would pass.  The entire grad student population of the department complained to the department head and the university as a group, but were ignored.  Unfortunately, this sort of thing is not uncommon.  I've never been associated with a grad program that actually treated all students fairly and evaluated them strictly on ability or the quality of their work.

I'm not trying to make you paranoid - I don't know your advisor or program - I'm just saying that you should be aware that in most programs the biggest part of getting a PhD is making your advisor happy and satisfying their personal whims.  And I can tell you from experience, that many of these people are immature and arrogant, do not take any kind of questioning or constructive criticism well, and have very specific ideas in their minds about what it means to "pay your dues" to get a PhD, which may be everything from extra academic work to sleeping in the lab to picking up their dry cleaning for them.  Some will even nearly write you off on day one if you didn't go to the right undergrad institution.  Most view your RA position as them doing you a favor, and expect you to do a sufficient amount of foot kissing in gratitude for it.  Your advisor's main interest is advancing their own career, and they see you as a tool to get there.  I know grad students who completed thesis work but were essentially held hostage by their advisors for additional years in order to work on projects that only helped the advisor.  Unfortunately, they had no choice.  Not only did they need to satisfy the advisor to get the degree, but they had no hope of landing a decent job without a glowing letter of recommendation.  Hopefully, your advisor is not one of these people.

My advice is that if you want to get through grad school, the work that is the highest priority for you is whatever your advisor says it is - and that may not necessarily be what you or anyone else thinks it should be, or what you are technically "obligated" to do.  I guarantee you that your department does not feel obligated to give you a degree, even if you do great work.  That isn't fair, but it's the way things are in the academic world.  If you want a PhD, you usually just have to suck it up, play whatever games your advisor says you have to, and then get the hell out.

So, by all means look out for your own interests, but just be very careful.

Comment: This is written in a slightly gloomier fashion than necessary, but contains some good points. E.g. "Your advisor's main interest is advancing their own career, and they see you as a tool to get there." This is certainly true most of the time. There are certainly exceptions to this rule (e,g, some people on this site), but look for clear signs your adviser is the exception before assuming he is. Also "just be very careful.". Always a good idea. Also " even if they at first appear to be." Yes, things are not always what they appear to be. And a little paranoia is not such a bad thing.

Comment: Having said that, some of these factor are heavily field dependent. E.g. a PhD is a subject like math and a PhD in a experimental science can be somewhat different experiences. And abuse is much more common in the latter case.

Answer (score -1):

I've been out of academia for thirty years.  So I'm sure it's completely different.  But one thing I've learned in the office environment is to happily accept any opportunity to serve that's presented.  It builds my resume and my visibility.

Comment: In academia, there are many opportunities to serve, and someone who doesn't know how to say "no" is likely to get endlessly bogged down in work that does not further his/her career.

Comment: The key is balance. Someone who says "yes" to everything will end up overwhelmed and unable to be productive. Someone who says "no" to everything will end up off the main track, and their career will not progress. There is not so much difference between business and academia, really: in both, you have to wisely decide when to help someone with projects they are interested in, to promote a team environment and to build good will.